# How To Find USB Drive in Video Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a lot of images, audio files, and videos in my USB drive titled "F:", but I can't seem to find that folder anywhere in the file browser in the video editor.  I searched documents, downloads, users, desktop, etc, but it seems to not be anywhere.  On my computer the USB drve is saved under "This PC", but I don't see anything like that in blender's video editor.

Answer (score 1):

The USB drive can be accessed by typing its drive letter `F:` into the field that displays the current path.

[image: Enter path]

Alternatively you can open the sidebar, either by clicking on the arrow icon on the left-hand side or by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image: Open sidebar]

There you can see a list of all the available volumes, including USB drives. Select the one you want to access and the file browser will display its files.

[image: Volumes]